# TypeError: theModel is not a constructor?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

How to fix error?

There is a save method in my dao:

`DeliveryLine.dao.ts`:

```
import{Injectable}from"@nestjs/common";
impoet{InjectConnection}from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import{Connection}from "mongoose"
import{DeliveryLine, DeliveryLineSchema}from "../../mongo/schema/DeliveryLine.schema"
import{DeliveryLineFilterDto} from "../dto/DeliveryLineFilter.dto"

@Injectable()
export class DeliveryLineDao{
  @InjectConnection("std")
  private connection:Connection;
  collectionName = DeliveryLine.collectionName;
  schema = DeliveryLineSchema;

  async save(model:DeliveryLine):Promise<DeliveryLine>{
    let theModel = this.connection.model(this.collectionName,this.schema);
    model.lastDate = new Date();
    let doc = new theModel(model);
    let newDoc = await doc.save().then((value)=>{return value.toObject();}).catch((e)=>{let errMsg = "save is called for:" + JSON.stringify(model) + "with error:" + e; throw new Error(e);});
return newDoc;
}
```

I want to test my function save to pass jest.

`DeliveryLine.spec.ts`:

```
import *as mongoose from "mongoose";
import{Test}from "@nestjs/testing";
import{DeliveryLine }from "../schema/DeliveryLine.schema";
import{DeliveryLineDao }from "./DeliveryLine.dao";
impoet{ConfigModule} from "@nestjs/config";

let service:DeliveryLineDao;

describe("test",()=>{
let deliveryLineInput ={
   UUID:"UU1",
   part:"1",
}
let connection = {
    model:jest.fn(()=>{
    return {
        save:jest.fn().mockImplementation(()=>Promise.resolve(jest.fn().mockImplementation()).then(()=>({toObject:jest.fn().mockImplementation(()=>Promise.resolve(deliveryLineInput))}))),
};
}),
};

beforeEach(async () ={
  const model = await Test.createTestingModule({
   import:[ConfigModule.forRoot()],
   provides:[DeliveryLineDao,{provide:"stdConnection",useValue:connection}],}).compile();
   service = module.get<DeliveryLineDao>(DeliveryLineDao);
});
test("to save deliveryLine", async () =>{
   let result = new DeliveryLine();
   result = deliveryLineInput;
   let deliveryLineSaved = await service.save(result);
   export(deliveryLineSaved).toBeTruthy();
   export(deliveryLineSaved).toBe(result);
});
})
})
```

My test is run error why did I run success for the test?

Jest test error:

> TypeError: theModule is not a constructor
> model.lastDate = new Date();
> let doc = new theModel(model);